# How can I create a Table like this in Latex?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

How can I create a table like this in Latex?

[image]

I have tried but it didn't work. I need also that it is enumerated so that it appears in the List of Tables. It doesn't matter if it is not coloured, as long as the first two rows are bold.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Number of cells per type} \\
 \hline

 a& b& c& d& e\\ 
  \hline
 44 & 39 & 7 & 32 &22 \\ 

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. First of all, please try to ask one question per thread. And, please show us what you have tried so far. This is not a do-it-for-me site.

Comment: \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Number of cells per type} \\
 \hline

 a& b& c& d& e\\ 
  \hline
 44 & 39 & 7 & 32 &22 \\ 
 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Comment: Please add it in your question and kindly make it compilable.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Do you need the first two columns to be narrower than the next three, as appears to be the case in the screenshot you posted? Please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you to use `booktabs` for professional tables.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\chapter{My chapter}
\begin{table}[htb]\centering
\caption{Your table\label{tab:yourtab}}
\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{ |C|C|C|C|C| } 
\hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bfseries Number of cells per type} \\
 \hline
 \bfseries a& \bfseries b& \bfseries c& \bfseries d& \bfseries e\\ 
  \hline
 44 & 39 & 7 & 32 &22 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]\centering
\caption{My suggestion\label{tab:mytab}}
\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{*5C} 
\toprule
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Number of cells per type} \\
 \midrule
 \bfseries a& \bfseries b& \bfseries c& \bfseries d& \bfseries e\\ 
  \midrule
 44 & 39 & 7 & 32 &22 \\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was thinking about

Comment: Is there, by any chance, a way to put "Table 1.2: My suggestion" under the table and not above?

Comment: @FedericaBenassi Yes, just put the `\caption...` after `\end{tabularx}`.

Answer (score 8):

There is also a really handy online tool called [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

It lets you input your data (you can even upload it from file), and adapt it WYSIWYG-style. It will then generate the correct LaTeX code for you to copy/paste into you document.

Edit: As suggested by Sanctus, here is the code that Tables Generator output me (after 2 minutes of data entry).

It does give really nice results for relatively simple tables with standard settings (colors, borders, font style, etc), but if you need something fancy, it probably won't provide enough. But I always use it as a starting point, to get the general structure working. Everything else I can then adapt myself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC} 
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC}\textbf{\tiny{Number of cells per type}}} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{DAE8FC} 
        \textbf{a}     & \textbf{b}     & \textbf{c}    & \textbf{d}    & \textbf{e}    \\ \hline
        44             & 39             & 7             & 32            & 22            \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output Table]

Comment: Simply the best answer here. Instead of fish, gives the rod!

Comment: @Sanctus - Have you actually looked at the quality of the LaTeX code produced by the tablegenerators.com site?

Comment: @Mico,  Im no Latex guru, but looked legit to me. Actually, just yesterday I copy-pasted whole table from there as it is. I found only stupid style formatting, probably related to the border configuration i set, cause it generates to much buzz. Otherwise it was ok.

Comment: May be @sara can also post resulting code for topic starter, just to compare to others.

Comment: Good point Sanctus, I've edited my answer!
@Mico, Tablesgenerator is obviously not the answer to every problem you can possibly have with tables in Latex, but it's definitely a good starting point. And with OPs relatively simple table, it does provide a great tool.

Comment: @Sanctus Tables Generator is good, but if you look from the eye of a person who can create (simple) tables himself, you will find that all tools for this will become unnecessary. Human-made are always far better than computer-made.

Comment: @JouleV, i heard that human-typed documents, books and articles are far better than generated-by some computer program called "latex".

Comment: @Sanctus That depends on your opinion. If you like Table Generator, use it. If you don't like LaTeX, don't use it. However, from my point of view, I don't like any automated generator, even LyX. I only need a coding-like software and I love coding every characters myself.

Answer (score 7):

Don't mix-and-mismatch visual cues and metaphores: if you employ colored rows, don't employ horizontal rules. And, for sure, you can omit all vertical rules -- they're not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sffamily
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional
\setlength\tabcolsep{9pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{ ccccc } 
 %\hline
 \rowcolor{LightBlue} \multicolumn{5}{c}{Number of cells per type} \\
 %\hline
 \rowcolor{LightBlue} a & b & c & d & e\\ 
 %\hline
 44 & 39 & 7 & 32 & 22 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice remark and a good suggestion (+1).

Answer (score 5):

A mix-and-match with colors and using something as a starting point

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables\newpage
    \begin{table}[]
        \begin{tabular}{!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}}
            \arrayrulecolor{cyan}\hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} 
            \multicolumn{5}{!{\color{cyan}\vrule}l!{\color{cyan}\vrule}}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}Number of cells per type} \\ \arrayrulecolor{cyan}\hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} 
            a            & b            & c            & d           & e           \\ \arrayrulecolor{cyan}\hline
            1            & 2            & 3            & 4           & 5           \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{a}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

[image]

PS: Feel free to play with colors (I right now, do not have the necessary things to find out the colors) and I was lazy enough not to input your numbers (sorry `;-)`)

Comment: Needless to load `colortbl`: the `table` option of `xcolor` does it for you.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the remark, updated my answer.